# Should hamburger be in list?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a menu which collapses when the width of the page is small to only show the active link and a hamburger menu. My question is, in this scenario, should the hamburger by separate from the UL tag or should it sit within?

**Option 1:**

```
<div class="header">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li class="inactive"><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="burger">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

**Option2:**

```
<div class="header">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li class="inactive"><a href="#">Test</a></li>
        <li class="inactive"><a href="#" class="burger">&#9776;</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I know it's only a little thing, but I've always wondered about similar things (i.e should the logo also sit within the menu links if they are next to each other?).

Comment: hamburger has no place inside ul. the menu could be triggered by something else, the ux guy may replace the hamburger with something else. the list should have the items and just that.

Comment: Either am I stupid or i really dont understand what your point is. Could you wrap it up to one sentence what you want?

Comment: As a side note - a lot of studies has been made regarding the widely used hamburger menu button, and it's actually not very great in a UX perspective since it doesn't encourage the users to move around on your site.

Comment: @RobinDorbell That's a fair point, although I would say that it's only a hamburger on mobiles, and that's a fair price to pay for using the site on a phone in my personal opinion.

Comment: @Jimmy I hear you, but do keep in mind that mobile is taking over as the main browser type. And there are more intuitive ways to handle the meny. But it, of course, also depends on what kind of site you're building.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Semantically, it should reside outside of the `ul` since it is not a list item.

Comment: Ok, that answers my question, thank you. I can't mark as an answer just yet.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should separate the burger from `<ul>` tags. So I'd choose the first option.

And give an active class for ul like here:

http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-a-responsive-menu-with-html-css-jquery#html-structure